# dividing columns by another column dplyr R

Tags: r, dplyr, divide

I do this on a table:

```
tmp %>%
mutate(sum_onCPA = rowSums(select(., setdiff(colnames(.),NON_CPA_VARIABLES)))) %>%
mutate_at(vars(CPA_A01: CPA_U), (./ sum_onCPA))
```

so I want to divide each column CPA_A01 to CPA_U (65 columns) by the sum on the columns (sum_onCPA) but I get the error

```
Error in is_fun_list(.funs) : object 'sum_onCPA' not found
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can call .$sum_onCPA:

```
set.seed(100)
tmp = data.frame(matrix(runif(25),ncol=5))
NON_CPA_VARIABLES = c("X1","X5")

tmp = tmp %>% 
mutate(sum_onCPA = rowSums(select(., setdiff(colnames(.),NON_CPA_VARIABLES))))
```

You can do

```
tmp %>% mutate_at(vars(X2:X4),function(i)i/.$sum_onCPA)
```

Credit to @ronakshah, who pointed out a neater version:

```
tmp %>% mutate_at(vars(X2:X4),~.x/sum_onCPA)

          X1        X2        X3        X4        X5 sum_onCPA
1 0.30776611 0.2721193 0.3515583 0.3763224 0.5358112  1.777789
2 0.25767250 0.4277649 0.4644980 0.1077371 0.7108038  1.899180
3 0.55232243 0.3673089 0.2780738 0.3546173 0.5383487  1.008199
4 0.05638315 0.4189724 0.3054667 0.2755609 0.7489722  1.304522
5 0.46854928 0.1048991 0.4698105 0.4252905 0.4201015  1.623104
```

We can check if above is correct using base R sweep:

```
tmp[,c("X2","X3","X4")] = sweep(tmp[,c("X2","X3","X4")],1,tmp$sum_onCPA,"/")
tmp
              X1        X2        X3        X4        X5 sum_onCPA
1 0.30776611 0.2721193 0.3515583 0.3763224 0.5358112  1.777789
2 0.25767250 0.4277649 0.4644980 0.1077371 0.7108038  1.899180
3 0.55232243 0.3673089 0.2780738 0.3546173 0.5383487  1.008199
4 0.05638315 0.4189724 0.3054667 0.2755609 0.7489722  1.304522
5 0.46854928 0.1048991 0.4698105 0.4252905 0.4201015  1.623104
```

Comment: true @RonakShah, thanks for pointing out, yeah it works. Ok i edit my answer